# C++ linux resize Xterm

Tags: c++, linux, resize, size, xterm

I'm trying to resize Xterm window after created, whitout Xlib because I tried and it's bugged. (if you want to know more about that take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014566/input-stream-dont-work-with-this-function?noredirect=1#comment44416536_28014566

I see it's possible with AINSI escape sequence, but it seems to didn't work on my Xterm, why ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please improve your linked question, or put the full context here. This way it's not a valid question for SO.

Comment: What I want is just to resize a Xterm window...

Comment: I doubt this works using `termios`, but anyway as stated: Improve one of these questions to clarify, but don't double post.

Comment: So the use of termios can make the problem ? They are two different question, this is just "how resize xterm" the other is "why the code randomly work". Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post the exact links for what you've found (markup syntax: `[<link-text>](<url>)` ) please?

Comment: Here is the code who i'm using : [Xlib search a window by his name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910906/xlib-test-window-names/27913084#27913084)

Answer (score 0):

To the first question: the [resize](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program would send the given escape sequence for its "-s" option.  However, the feature is often turned off by packagers who feel that allowing an escape sequence to resize your terminal can be harmful.  It can be turned on via menu (control/right/mouse *Allow Window Ops*) or using an X resource setting *allowWindowOps*