# createNotify event called too often

Tags: c, event-handling, xlib, xserver, window-management

I wrote the following code to detect when a window is created on the screen by another application (not by my code):

```
Display* display = XOpenDisplay(":0");
XSetWindowAttributes attributes;
attributes.event_mask = SubstructureNotifyMask | StructureNotifyMask;
Window win = XDefaultRootWindow(display);
XChangeWindowAttributes(display, win, CWEventMask, &attributes);

while (1) {
   XEvent event;
   XNextEvent(display, &event);
   if (event.type == CreateNotify)
      puts("create Notify event occured\n");
}
```

The code basically works, however, I noticed that, when I start an application (e.g. terminal) the `CreateNotify` event seems to be fired multiple times. Can anybody explain why? I would have expected that `CreateNotify` will only be fired **once** for every started application/window. How do I have to modify the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The events are for child windows.  Per [the Xlib Programming Manual](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/create.html),  "Creating any children ... generates an event."  A typical X application includes numerous child windows, and you're seeing each of them.

When you get the event, check `event.xcreatewindow.parent` (`XEvent` is a union per [the reference](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/structures.html)).  If that is `win`, the root window, you have a top-level window.  Otherwise, you have a child window.  Try:

```
if ( (event.type == CreateNotify) && (event.xcreatewindow.parent == win) )
    puts("top-level create Notify event occured\n");
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. tried it but it seems that `event` has no member called `parent`: `‘XEvent {aka union _XEvent}’ has no member named ‘parent’`

Comment: ah ok, thank you i's now compilable, but unfortunately the behavior is the same.

Comment: @Moonlit maybe the other windows are the chrome added by the window manager, then.  Use [XFetchName](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XFetchName.html) (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27910906/2877364)) to look at the window names and see if that gives you any ideas.  Since every application will have a different configuration of windows, this might be a tricky one.

Comment: alright, I'll investigate this and post my solution as soon I've got it working.  In the end I just want to get notified when an application gets started/displayed, and then put it to a specified location on the screen with a specified size. Do you think I am on the right track with this approach above, or do you think there might be an easier solution?

Comment: @Moonlit [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/startup-notification-spec/)?  Logging off for the day.  Good luck!

Comment: Top-level windows are created right and left by as much as moving your mouse (e.g. tooltips are top-level windows). You are on a wrong track. It looks like you are trying to replicate or amend window manager functionality. It is not going to work. You need to write a window manager, or interface with your existing window manager (via dbus or whatever).